# How do I use the Silicon Laboratories IDE with SDCC?

Tags: ide, microcontroller, 8051, sdcc

I'm thinking about using a microcontroller with an 8051 core from Silicon Laboratories.
I hope that I can use C rather than assembly language, so I installed SDCC.

I installed the "Silicon Laboratories IDE" to download the executable binaries to the on-chip Flash program memory.
It also supposedly can be set up (under the Project > Tool Chain Integration menu)
to use "any" 8051 compiler.

I tried to set it up to use SDCC, but every time I hit the "Assemble/Compile File" button it tells me
"Compiler process did not sucessfully complete."

How do I get new C code I write onto the SiLabs C8051F310 chip?
Is there a web site with a step-by-step HOWTO?
(Would it be easier to use a MAKEFILE that calls SDCC, only using the "Silicon Laboratories IDE" for the very last step of downloading the executable binary to the chip?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with [***Silicon Labs Application Note 198 - INTEGRATING SDCC 8051 TOOLS INTO THE SILICON LABS IDE***](http://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/an198.pdf)<sup>*</sup>.  It is written for an older version of the IDE, but the general configuration should remain the same.  It is probably important to note that [AN198 needs updating for SDCC 3.0.0](http://www.cygnal.org/ubb/Forum10/HTML/000122.html).  Additional information from the Silicon Labs [MCU User Forum](http://www.silabs.com/support/forums/Pages/default.aspx?cm_sp=%3CWebParts%3E-_-%3CMCUSupport%3E-_-%3CForums%3E) or [Microcontrollers Knowledge Base](http://www.silabs.com/support/knowledgebase/Pages/McuKB.aspx) may prove useful as well.

The [***SDCC Compiler User Guide***](http://sdcc.sourceforge.net/doc/sdccman.pdf)<sup>*</sup> can be useful if additional command line options are desired.

The [Silicon Labs USB Debug Adapter](http://www.silabs.com/products/mcu/Pages/USBDebug.aspx) can be used with the [Silicon Labs IDE](http://www.silabs.com/products/mcu/Pages/SiliconLaboratoriesIDE.aspx) and the on-chip debug/programming circuitry of the [*C8051F310*](http://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/C8051F31x.pdf)<sup>*</sup> for programming the MCU and debugging your code.

<sup>* PDF Link</sup>

Comment: Excellent, this looks like a perfect answer. Let me make sure it actually works before I hit the big "accept" button ...